# Black image is received after being sent over socket from android client

Tags: python, java, android, image, sockets

I have a TCP connection between my android app and Desktop PC, where I want to send the ImageView via socket. My problem is that the image is apparently sent successfully as it has 9.7KiB. However when I try visualizing this image I get a black image and no apparent errors are thrown in the Android Studio IDE.

[image]

The android app that sends an image:

```
private ImageView mImageView;
mImageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.frame_image);
private final OnClickListener mOnClickListener = new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        switch (view.getId()) {
            case R.id.button_camera:
                if (!Check.isFastClick()) {
                     return;
                  }
                  if (mCameraHandler != null) {
                     if (mCameraHandler.isOpened()) {
                          if (checkPermissionWriteExternalStorage()) {
                            Drawable drawable = mImageView.getDrawable();
                            Bitmap bitmap = getBitmapFromDrawable(drawable);
                            ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new  ByteArrayOutputStream();
                            bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 0, baos);
                            byte[] array = baos.toByteArray();
                            SendImageClient sendImageClient = new SendImageClient();
                            sendImageClient.execute(array);
                              }
                        }
                 }
            break;
        };

public Bitmap getBitmapFromDrawable(Drawable drawable){
    Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(drawable.getIntrinsicWidth(),drawable.getIntrinsicHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
    canvas.drawColor(Color.WHITE);
    drawable.draw(canvas);
    return bitmap;
}



    public class SendImageClient extends AsyncTask<byte[], Void, Void> {
          @Override
           protected Void doInBackground(byte[]... voids) {
        
                try {
                    Socket socket= new Socket("192.168.0.14",9999);
        
                    OutputStream out = socket.getOutputStream();
                    DataOutputStream dataOutputStream= new DataOutputStream(out);
                    dataOutputStream.write(voids[0],0,voids[0].length);
                    dataOutputStream.close();
                    out.close();
                    socket.close();
        
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                return null;
            }
        }
```

activity_main.xml

```
<com.serenegiant.widget.UVCCameraTextureView
    android:id="@+id/camera_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/menu_layout" />

<com.serenegiant.widget.AutoFitTextureView
    android:id="@+id/textureView"
    android:layout_width="480px"
    android:visibility="invisible"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/menu_layout"
    android:layout_height="640px" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/frame_image"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@id/camera_view"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@id/camera_view"
    android:layout_alignRight="@id/camera_view"
    android:layout_alignTop="@id/camera_view" />
```

Server script.py

```
from socket import *

port = 9999
s = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM)
s.bind(('', port))
s.listen(1)
conn, addr = s.accept()
print("Connected by the ",addr)


with open('/home/pi/Desktop/frames_saved/image.jpg', 'wb') as file:
    while True:
        data = conn.recv(1024*8)
        if not data: break
        file.write(data)


conn.close()
```

Why am I getting a black image, and how can I get the actual image being displayed in ImageView sent to the desktop?

Answer (score 0):

This code only create a empty bitmap

```
Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(mImageView.getWidth(), mImageView.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
```

getBitmap from ImageView

```
ImageView mImageView = findViewById(R.id.image);
Drawable drawable = mImageView .getDrawable();

Bitmap bitmap = getBitmapFromDrawable(drawable);
```

```
public Bitmap getBitmapFromDrawable(Drawable drawable){
        Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(drawable.getIntrinsicWidth(),drawable.getIntrinsicHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
        canvas.drawColor(Color.WHITE);
        drawable.draw(canvas);
        return bitmap;
    }
```

Comment: It gives me this: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.graphics.Bitmap android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable.getBitmap()' on a null object reference
        at com.MyApp.MainActivity$14.onClick(MainActivity.java:1379)

Comment: I has edited my answer. it can help you.

Comment: Unfortunately for me, it still gives the same error at this line: Bitmap bitmap = getBitmapFromDrawable(drawable);. The error is again java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.graphics.Bitmap android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable.getBitmap()' on a null object reference. However, I have edited my code with your reference

Comment: ensure your imageView has data. you can add `app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/xxxx" />`in your xml `<ImageView/>` or `ImageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.xxx)`

Comment: I did try researching but adding either lines will give errors. Adding the app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/xxxx" /> will give Cannot resolve symbol '@android:drawable/xxx. Whereas, mImageView.setImageResource(test); where test =1 will give  android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0xa

Comment: XXX means /res/drawable  source. please choice a real resouce xml in /res/drawable        mImageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.??????) ?????? is drawable resourceId.

Comment: do not just copy code . please understand.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/239636/discussion-between-john-jones-and-yan-sam).